# Lookup Field Displays All Records

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-portals

I'm building an employee self service portal via Dynamics 365, and when I use the lookup field to display my name in a form other employee names are displayed too:

[image: multiple employees]

I've been fiddling with the security roles for a while now and still cant seem to get it to display a single employee name.

I'm also planning to do it a different way by filling up the employee name based on the username on the upper right.

[image: Username]

How do you guys suggest I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Portals won't use any CRM Security role concepts as it's for CRM users. Portal is built on top of Contact entity. Contact is Portal user & Web role will control his/her access.

You have to [Entity Form Metadata](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/entity-form/entity-form-metadata/) to populate the fields per your need. The contact lookup can be filled in by current login Portal user this way. Even you can implement something like manage/restrict the Contacts only from your parent Account in that lookup easily.